# libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: centos6

Having issues running yum or rpm after removing a duplicate package libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 (already had libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.i686 installed).

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 10 2013, 22:48:45)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

This is running on CentOS 6.4 by the way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Those are not duplicate packages. You are going to have to manually restore it.

Comment: I had to extract the rpm file on my computer and manually copy the two files libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1 and libgcc_s.so.1 to their correct locations. All sorted now!